# Applying Date Operation to Entire Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': np.repeat(2018,12), 'month': range(1,13)})
```

In this data frame, I am interested in creating a field called 'year_month' such that each value looks like so:

```
datetime.date(df['year'][0], df['month'][0], 1).strftime("%Y%m")
```

I'm stuck on how to apply this operation to the entire data frame and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join both columns converted to `string`s and for `month`s add [`zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
df['new'] = df['year'].astype(str) + df['month'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
```

Or add new column `day` by [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), convert columns [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and last [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['new'] = pd.to_datetime(df.assign(day=1)).dt.strftime("%Y%m")
```

If multiple columns in `DataFrame`:

```
df['new'] = pd.to_datetime(df.assign(day=1)[['day','month','year']]).dt.strftime("%Y%m")
```

---

```
print (df)
    month  year     new
0       1  2018  201801
1       2  2018  201802
2       3  2018  201803
3       4  2018  201804
4       5  2018  201805
5       6  2018  201806
6       7  2018  201807
7       8  2018  201808
8       9  2018  201809
9      10  2018  201810
10     11  2018  201811
11     12  2018  201812
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': np.repeat(2018,12), 'month': range(1,13)})
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)

In [212]: %timeit pd.to_datetime(df.assign(day=1)).dt.strftime("%Y%m")
10 loops, best of 3: 74.1 ms per loop

In [213]: %timeit df['year'].astype(str) + df['month'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
10 loops, best of 3: 41.3 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to create the `datetime` objects directly from the source data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [date(i, j, 1) for i, j \
                   in zip(np.repeat(2018,12), range(1,13))]})

#           date
# 0   2018-01-01
# 1   2018-02-01
# 2   2018-03-01
# 3   2018-04-01
# 4   2018-05-01
# 5   2018-06-01
# 6   2018-07-01
# 7   2018-08-01
# 8   2018-09-01
# 9   2018-10-01
# 10  2018-11-01
# 11  2018-12-01
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an apply function such as:

```
df['year_month'] = df.apply(lambda row: datetime.date(row[1], row[0], 1).strftime("%Y%m"), axis = 1)
```